# Overflow - scroll when content within is absolute

Tags: html, css

as you can see below, I have a div that I would like to use overflow on.

But the content within uses absolute positioning and so it appears despite the overflow:

```
  .media_upload{
    .results { height:200px;  overflow-y: scroll; }
    .results .media-grid a{ float: left; margin:0 0 10px 10px; width:90px; height:90px; border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); margin: 0 0 18px 20px; padding: 4px;}
    .results  .media-grid img{clip: rect(0px, 90px, 90px, 0px); position:absolute}
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` to `.results` or `.media_upload`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 .media_upload{
    .results { height:200px; overflow: scroll;
 }
    .results .media-grid a{ float: left; margin:0 0 10px 10px; width:90px; height:90px; border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); margin: 0 0 18px 20px; padding: 4px;}
    .results  .media-grid img{clip: rect(0px, 90px, 90px, 0px); position:absolute}
  }
```

give html code also... using css only its not complete

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute` from `.results  .media-grid img`

`position` should use rarely it does problem many times